# How to start Internet Explorer browser instance with POST request

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a two part question:

1. is there any way to start Internet Explorer and have it immediately send a POST request to some URL? I know you can start IE with a URL and have to send a GET, but I need to do a POST
2. is there any way to start IE browser instance with a set of cookies?

Comment: Why do you want to start Internet Explorer? Why not make the HTTP request from some code? It can send an IE user agent string... Your question is not tagged with any languages or platforms... is this even a programming question?

Comment: I have a fat client (written in VB, but this does not matter) and we have a requirement to explicitly start a IE browser instance.  I need to know if we can send a POST when that window is opened up.

Answer (score 0):

No and no.

Well, theoretically the 2nd one is possible.  You can use the [Wininet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385473(VS.85).aspx) UrlCacheEntry functions to clean out all the old cookies and write whatever new cookies you want.  But that's a long painful road you really don't want to go down.

You should just use [cURL](https://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console).

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you're in control of the web application you can load a page that immediately does a POST through Javascript.

Comment: The main issue is that we have request parameters we need to POST over (it is a specific requirement not to use GET).   Even though we do control the website, getting the parameters to the site need to be a POST.

Comment: So send the parameters in the GET, and have the javascript on the page immediately POST those.